# Laravel Task Scheduller shown address as localhost when sent mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to send email via laravel task scheduller from database.

But, links are shown as localhost/blabla in received emails.
Same email template is working perfectly when i'm sending emails inside controller.

```
<a href="{{route('institution.profile', $inst_slug)}}">
```

This is the link inside email.

In Task Scheduler, it transforms something like this: localhost/blabla
But in controller, it transform normally like this: domainname.com/blabla

I think task scheduler does not know domainname, but how can i identify domain name for cron or task scheduler I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look at your `app.php` in your config folder there should be `url` parameter